# Create button that appends a html notifications div on every click

Tags: html

I want to create a new notification like this:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_alert.asp

everytime a specific button is clicked and append it under the other notifications. So create a new element everytime.

I first tried it with jquery but this seems not to allow me custom elements like this one, only text

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("h1").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#alerts").append(" <div>Appended text</div>");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button#btn1 {
  background: #0095ff;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

#alerts>div {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">Go</button>
<div id="alerts"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not initialize the `$(document).ready()` function correctly

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("h1").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });
});
```

Check out the fiddle for working example https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/3kq7z5wb/